# What is the lua equivalent of Python list.pop()?

Tags: python, list, lua, equivalent

I'm working on a project where the end-users will be running Lua, and communicating with a server written in Python, but I can't find a way of doing what I need to do in Lua.

I give the program an input of:

```
recipient command,argument,argument sender
```

I get an output of a list containing:

```
{"recipient", "command,argument,argument", "sender"}
```

Then, separate those items into individual variables. After that, I'd separate `command,argument,argument` into another list and separate those into variables again.

How I did it in Python:

```
test = "server searching,123,456 Guy" #Example
msglist = test.split()
recipient = msglist.pop(0)
msg = msglist.pop(0)
id = msglist.pop(0)

cmdArgList = cmd.split(',')
cmd = cmdArgList.pop(0)
while len(cmdArgList) > 0:
    argument = 1
    locals()["arg" + str(argument)]
    argument += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in your title is asking for something very specific: the Lua equivalent of getting a value from an array and removing it. That would be:

```
theTable = {};  --Fill this as needed
local theValue = theTable[1];  --Get the value
table.remove(theTable, 1);     --Remove the value from the table.
```

The question you ask in your post seems very open-ended.

Comment: That will work, assuming lua's split() creates a table. Takes an extra line, but no matter.

Comment: Unless you're using some Lua module that provides it, Lua doesn't have a `split` function. It has pattern matching, which you can use to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I found a page containing a variety of split functions, so the pop was all I really needed. And I'm certain with a bit more searching I could find something for locals().

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I wouldn't try to port the Python code as is. Here is a much simpler way to achieve the same thing in Lua:

```
local test = "server searching,123,456 Guy"
local recipient,cmd,args,id = s:match("(.+) (.-),(.+) (.+)")
```

After this step `recipient` is "server", `cmd` is "searching", `args` is "123,456" and `id` is "Guy".

I do not really understand what you are trying to do with `locals()["arg" + str(argument)]`, apparently you haven't posted all your code since accessing the local `arg1` all the time is a bit useless... But if you want to iterate the arguments just use `string.gmatch`:

```
for arg in args:gmatch("[^,]+") do
  -- whetever you want with arg
end
```